# Trouble retrieving data from web service using GSON

Tags: android, json, gson, webservice-client, arrays

I have tried a lot of samples and tutorials about GSON and how things would work using it such as:

- http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-parsing-json-data-with-gson/
- http://androidsmith.com/2011/07/using-gson-to-parse-json-on-android/

and etc.

My problem is that I have this json value returned by my `http://localhost:3000/users/1.json`, which is:

```
{
  "created_at": "2012-09-20T01:43:15Z",
  "id": 1,
  "name": "kevin",
  "updated_at": "2012-09-20T01:43:15Z"
}
```

Another is in this url `http://localhost:3000/users.json` which has a json value

```
[ {
    "created_at": "2012-09-20T01:43:15Z",
    "id": 1,
    "name": "kevin",
    "updated_at": "2012-09-20T01:43:15Z"
  }, {
    "created_at": "2012-09-20T01:43:33Z",
    "id": 2,
    "name": "pineda",
    "updated_at": "2012-09-20T01:43:33Z"
  }, {
    "created_at": "2012-09-20T01:46:08Z",
    "id": 3,
    "name": "raphael",
    "updated_at": "2012-09-20T01:46:08Z"
  }, {
    "created_at": "2012-09-20T16:13:42Z",
    "id": 4,
    "name": null,
    "updated_at": "2012-09-20T16:13:42Z"
  }, {
    "created_at": "2012-09-20T16:18:03Z",
    "id": 5,
    "name": null,
    "updated_at": "2012-09-20T16:18:03Z"
  }, {
    "created_at": "2012-09-20T16:19:23Z",
    "id": 6,
    "name": null,
    "updated_at": "2012-09-20T16:19:23Z"
  }, {
    "created_at": "2012-09-20T16:20:41Z",
    "id": 7,
    "name": null,
    "updated_at": "2012-09-20T16:20:41Z"
  } 
]
```

I am having a bit of a hard time parsing such data and getting it for storage purposes.

Comment: What did you try? Did you define a class for this and tried to call gson.fromJson with it?

Comment: i don't understand where the problem is?

Comment: have a look at [link](http://squiressquire.net16.net/JSONTutorial)

Comment: unless you need the serialization that gson does, i think it's easier to just manually parse the data using the built in JSONObject and JSONArray.

Comment: @Raphael, isn't my solution working for you? If so, let me know and I'll try to help...

Comment: Oh i forgot to say thanks, It worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to parse your JSON, you first need to create a class to *wrap* your data. In your case:

```
public class Item {
  @SerializedName("created_at")
  private String createdAt;
  @SerializedName("id")
  private int id;
  @SerializedName("name")
  private String name;
  @SerializedName("updated_at")
  private String updatedAt;
  //getters and setters
}
```

Then, in order to parse your **1st** JSON reponse, you just have to do:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Item item = gson.fromJson(your1stJsonString, Item.class);
```

Your **2nd** JSON response is a bit more tricky, because it's an array. The problem is that you can't simply do:

```
List<Item> item = gson.fromJson(your1stJsonString, List<Item>.class); //wrong!
```

The previous code fails because Java can't know the class of `List<Item>` due to [**type erasure**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

So you have to do it this way:

```
Type itemListType = new TypeToken<List<Item>>() {}.getType();
List<User> itemList = gson.fromJson(your2stJsonString, itemListType);
```

And that's all, once you have parsed your JSON response in your object (or list of objects) you can access all the retrieved data as usual:

```
String name = itemList.get(i).getName();
```

---

*Note 1*: Notice that I've set the types of attributes created_at and updated_at as just `String`, because it makes things easier. I usually do it this way, and then I parse the `Date` or any other *confictive* type. Anyway, if you want to directly parse the dates, I think you can use a **Custom Deserializer** following [**Gson's User Guide**](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-a-Deserializer).

---

*Note2*: The use of the annotation `@SerializedName` is interesting to separate the name of a field in the JSON response and in your app, in order to follow Java naming conventions...